# How to create Live Stats in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I am running an hyip website  I want to show new member who are registering to website. how  I can do it in laravel  mean users->+1 how to create query that show new registerations on website automatically

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried already?

Comment: The question is meaningless - what are you trying to do? Strangely, there are more clues in your follow up to the answer that was not accepted than in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [eloquent's](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent) `count`. Add it to your blade template

```
Total: {{ \App\User::count() }} users
```

to count users in `users` table.

If you wish to show only last registered users count

```
Last registered: {{ \App\User::where('created_at', '>', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subHour())->count() }} users
```

As a list:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    @foreach(\App\User::where('created_at', '>', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subHour())->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->take(10)->get() as $user)
       <tr><td>{{ $user->name }}</td><td>some more info</td></tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It should be mentioned, that better to get users in controller and pass the list to blade template.

Comment: thanks but i want to show live stats on home page  for example . 10 new registerations

Comment: What is live for you? 10 per seconds? 10 per last day? Do you need a js solution?

Comment: thanks  shukshin.ivan. please can you tell how i limit it  mean i want to show only last 10 with user name

Comment: You want to show them as a list, not as a count, don't you?

Comment: yes i want to show them in  list with there name name

Comment: Check it. I hope, you've understood the main idea

Comment: i should ad like  this value ='@foreach(\App\User::where('created_at', '>', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subHour())->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->take(10)->get() as $user)
   {{ $user->name }} <br>
@endforeach'   ?

Comment: Right, my code just displays a list of users with their names.

Comment: you helped me alot please last one.your code is working perfectlyt. if i want a table then. mean i want to show this in <tr></tr> and this talble will automatic for 10

Comment: Check. Actually, Stackoverflow is not for such help, you should have to do basics like html formatting or reading docs by yourself. That's why you have a lot of downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the users that registered in the last 24 hours, here is the query

```
$user_count = User::where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDay())->count()
```

Where User is your model, you can alter the Carbon instance and subtract hours, minutes or even seconds

Comment: in which blade i should use this query?

Comment: @WaqarAli no, then you pass it to the view like this -> view('yourview', ['user_count' => $user_count]), after that you can use it in your blade template like {{ $user_count }}, if you need it on all pages you might want to use a view composer https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#view-composers

Comment: i want to this  in table @foreach(\App\User::where('created_at', '>', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subHour())->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->take(10)->get() as $user)
   {{ $user->name }} <br>
@endforeach how to do it